# And / Or condition in Spring annotation based validation

Tags: spring, validation, annotations

I am using Spring 3 annotation based validation. I want to add a following validation for String fields

> Field can be Null **OR**  it should contain a non empty string

I know annotation like `@Null`, `@NotEmpty` but how I can use both with a OR condition?

---

**Solution:**

Using `@Size(min=1)` helps but it don't handle spaces. So added a custom annotation `NotBlankOrNull` which will allow `null` and non empty strings also it takes care of blank spaces. Thanks a lot @Ralph.
Here is my Annotation

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { NotBlankOrNullValidator.class })
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface NotBlankOrNull {
    String message() default "{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlankOrNull.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

Validator class

```
public class NotBlankOrNullValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotBlankOrNull, String> {

    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if ( s == null ) {
            return true;
        }
        return s.trim().length() > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(NotBlankOrNull constraint) {

    }
}
```

I have also updated it on my [site](http://www.ajinkyaparakh.com/2012/02/creating-custom-constraint-annotation.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*First of all, it is not Spring annotation based validation, it is JSR 303 Bean Validation, implemented for example by Hibernate Validation. It is really not spring related/*

You can not combine the annotations in an OR way*.

But there is a simple workaround for the not null constraint, because the most basic validations accept null as an valid input (therefore you often need to combine the basic vaidations and an extra @NotNull, if you want to have a "normal" behavior but not what you asked for).

For Example:
  `@javax.validation.constraints.Size` accept null as an valid input.

So what you need in your case is use `@Size(min=1)` instead of `@NotEmpty`.

BTW: Not `@NotEmpty` is just an combination of `@NotNull` and `@Size(min = 1)`

*except you implement it by your self.

Comment: Thanks a lot four suggestion and correcting me .I tried `@Size(min=1)` and it works for `null` and non empty strings. Just wondering how to deal with if user enters spaces?

Comment: @Ajinkya: have a look at the NotBlank Annotation source code. Again it is annoteted with NotNull. But it is validatedBy NotBlankValidator (fortunaly the NotBlankValidator return true (valid) for null). So you need your own Annotation but can reuse the Validator implementation> `@Constraint(validatedBy = { NotBlankValidator.class })@Target...@Retention...public @interface NotBlankOrNull`